# Apps Script Google Sheets Birthday Reminder Range in Array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I'm trying to write an automatic birthday reminder for my team.
It's supposed to check if a persons birthday is today and if so, send a mail to everyone else in the team.
In Google Sheets, the four columns are: name, surname, e-mail and birthday. First row are headers.
This is what I got so far (mostly copied):
`

```
function main() {
  // Load the sheet that contains the birthdays.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Geburtstage");

  // Get the last row in the sheet that has data.
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Load data in the first two columns from the second row till the last row. 
  // Remember: The first row has column headers so we don’t want to load it.
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows - 1, 4).getValues();

  // Use a for loop to process each row of data
  for(var index in range) {

    // For each row, get the person’s name and their birthday
    var row = range[index];
    var name = row[0];
    var birthday = row[3];

    // Check if the person’s birthday is today
    if(isBirthdayToday(birthday)) {
      //If yes, send an email reminder
      emailReminder(name);
    }
  }
}

// Check if a person’s birthday is today
function isBirthdayToday(birthday) {
  var today = new Date();
  if((today.getDate() === birthday.getDate()) &&
      (today.getMonth() === birthday.getMonth())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Function to send the email reminder
function emailReminder(name) {
  var subject = "Geburtstagerinnerung: " + name;
  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var body = name + " hat heute Geburtstag!";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

`

All that is missing is to replace the recipient by all e-mails in the third column, except for the person whos birthday it is.

My idea is, to save the range of the third column (e-mails) to an array, drop the e-mail whos birthday it is, and pass it to recipient as a comma separated string.
Afterwards reset the array in case two people have the same birthday.
My problem is, that I have no idea what I'm doing and all the solutions I found are overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function main() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  let recipients;
  vs.forEach((R,i) => {
    let d = new Date(R[3]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(dv == dtv) {
      recipients = vs.filter((r,j) => j != i ).map( r => r[2]).flat().join(",")
      GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients,`Todays ${R[0]} Birthday`,"");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It says recipients: undefined

Comment: Please provide a table of data that I can copy and paste to perform debugging.